# How to get the blank jtextfield?

Tags: java, algorithm, swing

I am building a calculator (gas law calculator) which has four text fields, and I need three fields to be filled by numbers to calculate the fourth value. The equation is v1/p1 = v2/p2. But the problem is I don't know which three values the user will fill. So I need to find an algorithm to check each text field and determine which is empty. I am using swing classes. Jut give me direction.

Thank you!

Comment: try to check it by someTextField.getText().length()

Comment: Better `someTextField.getText().trim().isEmpty()` This will ignore spaces as well.

Comment: Build an array of 4 JTextFields, and iterate over them to find the empty one, get the other texts, convert them by `Integer.parseInt (s[i]);`. Do a `switch (empty) { case 0..4: jtf[empty].setText "" + (formula); break; ...}` to fill the empty field.

Answer (score 3):

- [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)
- to try to avoiding [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)
- possible way could be [FocusListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html) also, notice [Focus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) is asynchronous

Comment: ... or an old fashioned JButton ("calculate"); :)

Comment: @user unknown right, but this is not required for JFormattedTextField with NumberFormatter, because its can returns null (required additional hack to force null for JFormattedTextField) or Number value

Answer (score 2):

Well, what do you expect the value of the "empty" field to be?

Of course it will be the empty string, `""`.

So just test for which fields contents `equal` the empty string (or have a length of 0).

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
private boolean validateField(JComponent component)
{
if (component.getText().trim().length() == 0){
   return false;
}
else{
   return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if JTextField is **empty** you just do it as follows:

**Example(sudo code):**

-> JTextField field = new JTextField("v1:");

-> if(field.getText().isEmpty == true){...}
   else{...}